# Spring MVC Properties Table

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, properties, applicationcontext

We are using Spring MVC + Hibernate.

We have a lookup table in our database. Would like to if there is anyway i can have the values loaded automatically to a bean/properties/map so that i dont have to access the database for every single time i need.

The table contents have to get loaded to the prop/bean/map during server startup.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Simply load the data in `@PostConstruct` callback:

```
@Service
public class ReferenceData {

    private Map cached//...

    @PostConstruct
    public void loadReferenceData() {
        //load from database and store in `cached` field
    }

}
```

Be careful, `@PostConstruct` is not transactional and cannot be, even when annotated with `@Transactional`.

Another approach is to take advantage of Hibernate L2 cache and query cache. Load data every time you need it from the database and let caching layer built into Hibernate handle it.

Comment: Is there any other solution like using start up listeners?

Comment: @user1102835 You mean other than `@PostConstruct`? In Spring there is also `init-method=""` and `InitializingBean` interface.